# Impossible to process multiple tables with ODBC connection in SSAS Tabular 2017

Tags: azure, ssas, compatibility, tabular, ssas-tabular

I'm currently building a cube in SSAS Tabular with compatibility level 1400 (on an Azure workspace server) and here is my problem. I have an ODBC connection to source my cube and I have to use a connection string and a SQL query for each tables I need (the connection string is always the same and the SQL query is always different).

When I have my first table (and only one table), I can Build, Process and Deploy easily without any problem. But, when I add a new table, I can't process anymore. I have that kind of message for both tables : `Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'Column' column does not exist in the rowset.`

I think the problem comes from the connection string which is the same for every table. I only have one Data source at the end because I only have one connection string for every table. In my opinion, it might be the cause of my problem but I'm not sure about that. Any idea ?

I hope I made myself clear.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. It was not related to my data source but to the table properties of each table.

Indeed, there was only the connection string in it and not the SQL query. I had to replace it with the correct M language query. It's still a bit strange because I had to make the same "Get Data" in Power BI to have the right M query and then copy and paste it to the table properties in SSAS. There should be a way to make it automatically I guess but I didn't find how.